# multipart/mixed HTTP request in actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, actionscript, odata

**Is there an easy way to make an multipart/mixed HTTP request in as3?**

I'm trying to reach LightSwitch server using OData protocol from flash. To send multiple commands at once you can combine them in one batch using HTTP request with "multipart/mixed" content type.

Here an example of HTTP requests with two commands:

```
Content-Type:multipart/mixed; boundary=batch

--batch
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=changeset


--changeset
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

PUT http://localhost:18065/ApplicationData.svc/Orders(3)/$links/User HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json;odata=verbose

{"uri": "http://localhost:18065/ApplicationData.svc/Users(4)"}


--changeset
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

MERGE http://localhost:18065/ApplicationData.svc/Users(3) HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json;odata=verbose
If-Match: W/"X'0000000000002715'"

{"Name": "User 3_"}
--changeset--
--batch--
```

Every part contains own HTTP headers and body. Response formatted the same way, with own http response code.
How to work with multiple HTTP requests in actionscript?